# CSS "active" font color, driving me nuts

Tags: css, css-selectors

This issue is killing me. I'm sure it's something simple, but not simple enough I guess.

I'm working on the website for a church, and the development URL is http://commonmandesign.com/sites/stpaul/home/

The problem, is that the "active" selection in the navigation bar turns white, against a white background, and I can't change it - no matter what I do. The last thing I tried was to add an "active" rule to turn the font black, but that didn't work. Then, just to see if it would work, I added "color: #000;" to every CSS rule that deals with the navbar, and it still turns white.

the CSS rules for the navbar are below. If anyone has any ideas, it would me much appreciated. I've been chasing down this bug on and off for 2 months.

Thanks!

```
.main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation ul.menu,
.site-navigation.main-navigation div.menu > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -4px;


}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li:last-child{
    background-image: none;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li a {
    color: #515659;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 23px 19px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*background: transparent url('images/divider.png') left center repeat-y;*/
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li:hover > a,
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #e9e9e9;
    background: #f29120;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -o-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-delay: 0.1s; /* W3C and Opera */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration:0.5s;
    animation-duration:0.5s;

}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .sub-menu,
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .children {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#fff;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    color: #515659;
    z-index: 99999;
    text-align: left;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .sub-menu ul,
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .children ul {
    border-left: 0;
    left: 190px;
    top: 0;

}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .sub-menu li {
    margin-right: 0px!important;
    background-image: none!important;
}
.site-navigation.main-navigation .sub-menu li a {
    text-transform: capitalize!important;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .sub-menu li:hover > a {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation ul.menu ul a,
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu ul ul a {
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    width: 160px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation ul.menu ul a:hover, .menu ul ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation ul.menu li:hover > ul,
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the rule that turns it white is more specific then the one that turns it black:

```
1 - .site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .current-menu-item > a {#white}
2 - .site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li a {#black}
```

1 is more specific then 2. Add this rule instead and it should turn black:

```
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .current-menu-item a {
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: why adding another rule if he can remove the rule that set the color to white? look at my answer

Comment: You are correct, however it is also good to know about the way CSS prioritize the rules using specificity.

Answer (score 0):

So both

```
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li:hover > a,
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #e9e9e9;
    background: #f29120;
    color: #fff;
...
```

and

```
.site-navigation.main-navigation ul.menu ul a:hover, .menu ul ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

have color:#ff which would turn the text white. In both of those cases on hover.

I think if you play around with those color values you'll find that the text won't be white on hover.

Comment: I should clarify...it's not on hover that's the problem, it's when it's static. When you're on the particular page, it's white on white. On hover, the background turns orange, so it's not an issue.

Comment: The text on the home page nav bar is grey for me on chrome. Could you specify which text is white?

Answer (score 0):

You have it right there in your css:

```
.site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .current_page_ancestor > a,  .site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .current-menu-item > a,  .site-navigation.main-navigation .menu .current-menu-ancestor > a, .entry-header-comments .read-more-button:hover, .buttonsx:hover, .error-text, .widget ul li ul li:hover { color: #fff; background: ;}
```

Line 71 (on chrome source). if you don't want it - remove it :)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is:

```
.share-items li a:hover {background:red !important;}
```